# How to have a single history from all bash terminals?

Tags: bash, history, command-history

I typically have multiple bash terminals open and I would like for the commands from all terminal sessions to go into a single history file, so I can see my command history chronological order across all terminal sessions.

For example, let's say I have two open bash terminals, A and B. In chronological order I issue various commands:

```
term_A: $ cmd1
term_A: $ cmd2
term_B: $ cmd3
term_A: $ cmd4
term_B: $ cmd5
term_B: $ cmd6
```

Later when I issue a `history` command, from any terminal (either A, B, or another new or existing termnal session), I should see the commands from both terminals in chronological order:

```
term_X: $ history
857 cmd1
858 cmd2
859 cmd3
860 cmd4
861 cmd5
862 cmd6
```

How do I configure my .bashrc and/or other settings to make this possible?

BTW I already have the below in my `~/.bashrc` but it seems to be insufficient for what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

Comment: Research material from our sister sites: [*Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1288/108618), [*Is it possible to make writing to .bash_history immediate?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/67283/693277)

Comment: Thank you, @KamilMaciorowski. I actually tried most of the .bashrc hacks in those answers before posting here and haven't managed to get them to work. With zsh this behavior seems to work right out of the box so I'm using that until I can work out how to get the same behavior from bash (on Ubuntu 18.04). Sorry for what appears to be a repeat question, I can delete if that's the community concensus.

Comment: It's not a duplicate if it's on a different SE site (unless [one posts the same question on different sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310); this is *not* the case here). Still, answers here will probably say what these under the linked questions say; so if the solution doesn't work for you, you should explicitly say so in the question body ([edit] it). Then the question may be "why it doesn't work? and how to make it work?" Note `.bashrc` edits will work for new shells. A single old shell (that behaves in the old way) may replace the history with its own version when it exits.

Answer (score 0):

In your .bashrc add the line `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'`

This comes from [here](http://northernmost.org/blog/flush-bash_history-after-each-command/) and has been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals)